# Retrieve data from dynamoDB back to local storage (Datastore) - Flutter

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I am new to Amplify datastore and decided to use Amplify Datastore with flutter app to provide offline mode feature to the users. I successfully implemented my project with Datastore but I would like to clear the local storage when the user logs out. And if logs back, I want user's data to be there but it seems like datastore sync data from local to cloud out of the box but do not sync cloud to local storage back since I can't see any records (After login back or after reinstalling).

So are we required to retrieve the data from dynamoDB using GraphQL APIs and then save it to the local datastore or is there any out-of-the-box function provided by Amplify to retrieve data from the cloud?

I also notice after a few logins and logouts it somehow fetched the data from the cloud and I was able to see the records on my application. Not sure what's going on :/

Answer (score 1):

Amplify DataStore by default automatically syncs all data from the backend to the local device. It sounds like already found out about DataStore.clear() and use that to clear local storage when the user logs out.

The next time the app starts and the user logs in datastore will connect to the backend. When the app makes the first query data will start syncing from the backend. If you want to cause sync to start earlier use DataStore.start(). In either case, the initial query might not return all the data that you want as sync takes time. You can wait for events that the data has been synced before running queries, or make sure there is a certain amount of data available before the query is run.

More info on [start and close methods](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/other-methods/q/platform/js/)

The event you can monitor to see if the datastore is ready and all data from the cloud has been synced locally is [ready](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/datastore-events/q/platform/js/#modelsynced)